# Populate Table from more than one drop-down list

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, dropdown

I'm trying to populate a Table after a user picks options from a drop down list when this options are picked the table should be populated based on selected options. I'm not sure how can I get this done and I've searched for tutorias etc but nothing helped me. So I'll be glad if someone can help somehow for example with small test codes etc.

I'm using PHP and the options for the drop-down list come from a MySQL-Database so in summary a person will choose a user from Users-drop down list after that a another option from different drop down list and then there's also going to be a date filter after 1, 2 or all 3 are selected a table will be produced based on the selected values.

So far I've no code done because I have no idea how to do it but I guess I need to put all 3 dropdown lists in a form and after submission I should produce the table, but how can I have more than one `<select> ..... </select>` in a `<form>` and submit them all simultaneously.

What I've done so far (I know it's unsafe and that mysql_* doesn't exist anymore in PHP7) but please don't criticize it.

**UPDATE**

```
//Database query for User drop-down(DD) population. 
    $sqlDD = " SELECT DISTINCT `user` FROM `users`  " ;
    $resultDD = mysql_query($sqlDD);

    //Database query for Status drop-down(DD) population.
    $sqlDDStatus =  " SELECT `status` FROM `status` WHERE `id` = 1 OR 
      `id` = 123 OR `id` = 182 OR `id` = 12 ";
    $resultDDStatus = mysql_query($sqlDDStatus); 

<form id="form1" name="form1" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">



            <select name="userSelect">

            <?php 
                 while($rowDD = mysql_fetch_array($resultDD)): 
                echo "<option value='" . htmlspecialchars($rowDD['user']) ."'>" . htmlspecialchars($rowDD['user']) ."</option>"; ?>
        <?php   endwhile; ?>


            </select>
             <!-- Second DD-list in the same form -->
            <select name="Status" style="max-width: 250px;" > 
        <?php 
                 while($rowDDS = mysql_fetch_array($resultDDStatus)):
                    echo "<option value='" . htmlspecialchars($rowDDS['status']) ."'>" . htmlspecialchars($rowDDS['status']) ."</option>"; ?>
        <?php   endwhile; ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value='Find'/>

            </form>



//Get the submited data
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])): ?>
            <?php echo 'This is submitted ' . $_POST['submit']; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I've added echo `'This is submitted ' . $_POST['submit'];`
because i wanted to see what is submitted but all it get's echoed out is only 
"Find".

Any ideas how can i get the data submitted from both 's in  the form and populate a table based on it ?

**UPDATE 2**
After getting an answer from other users I saw that my forms handles the data correctly but my question now is how can I use the data from the Submitted DDL Form and populate a table with them? So far I've tried the following:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])): ?>
        <?php $result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = 
        $_POST['userSelect']  AND (`id` = 1 OR `id` = 18)" );
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

and then in the table

```
<table>
<?php  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) :; ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['user']; ?></td>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

But I just don't get any response when I try it. How can I fix my problem and get the wanted output?

**EDIT**
I think that i've found my mistake after some research im not able to test the code now but i'm almost positive that you can't use `$_POST['userSelect']` in the Database query so i just need to assign `$_POST['userSelect']` to some variable before i use it in the query. So far i've gotten useful 1 little useful tip......  so disappointed from stackoverflow .......

Comment: That's not a question about code as long as you don't show even a single line (--> That's not how to use StackOverflow). About your work, try by yourself, experiment and you'll get answers quicker. Have you tried to build your form and get its data when submitted ? Have you tried to make a query to create a table ?

Comment: @AymDev Please look at the Updated Question.

Comment: Much better ! I'll give an answer.

Comment: Please look at **UPDATE 2** i've fixed a lot of issues but there is some things that remain and i'd really like to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basis HTML/PHP page for getting data from the backend to the frontend, this should get you started. Try to print the data (in the while loop on the HTML page).

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="dropdown.php" method="POST">
        <select name='options'>
            <option>option 1</option>
            <option>option 2</option>>
            <option>option 3</option>>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }else{
        if (!empty($_POST)){

            if(!empty($_POST['options'])){

                $option = $_POST['options'];

                $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE option='$option'";

                $res = $mysqli->query($query);

                while($data = $res->fetch_assoc()){

                    //print data to HTML page
                    print_f('%s, $s\n', $data['firstname'], $data['lastname']);

                }

            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please look at my Updated Question

Answer (score 0):

Your form is probably working, the reason you only get "Find" is because you are printing the `value` of the submit button.
To get an overview of your form data, try:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

You will get the other values of your form by using the `name` attribute of your `<select>` with `$_POST`:

```
echo $_POST['userSelect'];
echo $_POST['Status'];
```

By the way, you are using a deprecated extension ([written here for example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)), it is recommended to use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (especially PDO is recommended). If you are working with PHP 7, mysql_connect won't work as it has been removed.
And I'm not sure the use of `htmlspecialchars()` is relevant on each database data you use.

[PHP.net - print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) (See also [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php))
[PHP.net - $_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: Sadly i can't switch to myslqi_ right now. Anyways using `echo $_POST['userSelect'];` and `echo $_POST['Status'];` really does gives me the things i want my question now is how can i used the selected values and populate a table using them ? I tried with:
`<?php $result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = 
            $_POST['userSelect']  AND (`id` = 1 OR `id` = 18" );
            ?>` and Then
`<tr>
<?php  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) :; ?>
                <td><?php echo $row['user']; ?></td>`
               <?php endwhile; ?>`
all is in <table> tag

Comment: @Richard You should switch your work to MySQLi as soon as possible, and secure your code ([WikiHow - prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-SQL-Injection-in-PHP)). And to "populate a table" as you said, just need to do a `INSERT`. Just learn the basics of SQL, the CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) == `INSERT`, `SELECT`, `UPDATE` & `DELETE`. I recommend [sql.sh](http://sql.sh/) to learn a bit more :-)

Comment: i know SQL and i there is no need to insert something in the Database. The Database is already filled im just asking it to return to me some of data that is stored in it.

Comment: @Richard you wrote `:;` (last code block, 2nd line), isn't it the problem ?

Comment: writing `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) :; ?>` there is no problem closing the `while` this way because i end the while later with
`<?php endwhile; ?>` i've tested it with other inputs and it's okay. I just don't understand why when i use `user = $_POST['userSelect']` in the query, and use it to populate my table it doesn't produce no output and completly breaks the code.